# Saving objects to Realm

Tags: swift, realm

I try to save some objects to a Realm, but even after setting the member variables and saving it - after reading the Realm, the objects have their default values.

```
class Person: Object {
  @objc dynamic var Name: String = "test"
  @objc dynamic var Age: Int = 0;
}

do {
   let realm = try Realm();

   var p = Person();
   p.Name = "Poirot"
   p.Age = 55
            
   try realm.write {
       realm.add(p)
       print("Person:",p.Name);  // <-- Here its correct: "Poirot"
   }
} catch let error {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}

do {
   let realm = try Realm()
    
   let data = realm.objects(Person.self)
    
   for persons in data {
      print("Person:", persons.Name);  // <-- Here its wrong: "test"
   }
    
} catch let error {
   print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

After running this, it would print:

> Person: Poirot
>
> Person: test

Can someone explain me this behavior and tell me what I´m doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code - it works 100% for me. It outputs `Person: Poirot` twice. Please note that Uppercase should not be used for vars; Uppercase is reserved for Class, Struct and Enum names. It won't affect the code but does affect it's readability. e.g. `Name` should be `name` and `Age` should be `age` - it's just a coding thing. So, you're issue is not that code but something else *outside* of that code. I suggest crafting a brand new clean project, add Realm with Cocoapods and copy and paste the code (which is wha I did) and give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your code in foreground it is fine.
If you are on a background thread (a thread without a RunLoop) than you need to refresh your realm.

```
   let realm = try Realm()

   realm.refresh()

   let data = realm.objects(Person.self)

   for persons in data {
      print("Person:", persons.Name);  // <-- Here its wrong: "test"
   }
```

Have a look at the [Realm threading documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/advanced-guides/threading/) and scroll down to **Refreshing Realms**